# How to get Yarn Application Id for hive jdbc connection?

Tags: jdbc, hive, hadoop-yarn

Here is how i am running queries through hive jdbc

```
Class.forName(DRIVER);
Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
Response = Connection.createStatement();
ResultSet = Response.executeQuery(query);
```

I can see the application details in yarn ui. But now i want to get the application id for this job through java code, Is it possible to do so? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK the short answer is: not in older versions of Hive; possibly with recent versions, which let you retrieve some logs, which may contain the YARN ID.

Starting with Hive 0.14 you can set up *HiveServer2* to **publish the execution logs for the current Statement**; and in your client code you can use a Hive-specific API to fetch these logs (asynchronously just like Beeline client does, or just once when execution is over).

Quoting [Hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients)

> Starting with Hive 0.14.0, HiveServer2 operation logs are available
> for Beeline clients. These parameters configure logging:
>
> hive.server2.logging.operation.enabled
> hive.server2.logging.operation.log.location
> hive.server2.logging.operation.verbose *(Hive 0.14 to 1.1)*
> hive.server2.logging.operation.level *(Hive 1.2 onward)*
>
> Hive 2.0 adds the support of logging `queryId` and `sessionId` to HiveServer2 log file *(...)*

The source code for `HiveStatement` shows several non-JDBC methods such as `getQueryLog` and `hasMoreLogs` -- also `getYarnATSGuid` for Hive 2+ and other stuff for Hive 3+.
Here is the [link to the "master" branch on GitHub](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/jdbc/src/java/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveStatement.java), switch to whichever version you are using *(possibly an old 1.2 for compatibility with Spark)*.

For a dummy demo about how to tap the "Logs" methods, have a look at [that SO post with a snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35361810/5162372).

Comment: Those links to Hive JDBC API and "that post" are now obsolete.

Comment: Those links have been replaced _completely_.