# Query Hive SQL Using Jdbc Or Beeline, How to show progress of running map reduce jobs

Tags: java, sql, hive

I'm currently encountering a problem.
To execute hive sql and show the progress or detailed info of running queries.
I've read Hive Documents for help. But with hive-jdbc I can only wait until a query ends without any progress information, this is especially unacceptable when executing a large query which takes minutes or hours.
Is there any good solution to query hive sql and simultaneously get corresponding map-reduce job progress details?

Comment: Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33537776/how-to-get-yarn-application-id-for-hive-jdbc-connection and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356788/how-to-capture-a-hive-exit-status-or-error-code-using-jdbc-api >> with a stress on _"That stuff is not really documented, but there's the source code"_...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter really appreciate. Just found getQueryLog in HiveStatement.java. I only checked jdbc.Statement before and ignored HiveStatement. Ooops